# I have a few questions about reference variable

Tags: c++, reference

```
typedef struct
{
    int xpos = 0;
    int ypos = 0;
}Point;

Point& PA(const Point &p1, const Point &p2)
{
    Point *pptr = new Point;
    pptr->xpos = p1.xpos + p2.xpos;
    pptr->ypos = p1.ypos + p2.ypos;
    return *pptr;
}

int main()
{
Point *pptr1 = new Point;
pptr1->xpos = 3;
pptr1->ypos = 20;

Point *pptr2 = new Point;
pptr2->xpos = 70;
pptr2->ypos = 7;

Point &ref = PA(*pptr1, *pptr2);

delete pptr1;
delete pptr2;
delete &ref;

return 0;
}
```

1. First of all, I have a question about how to declare a variable to return a local variable as a reference type. The return type of the function PA is Point& as you can see. Inside the definition of a function, however, it returns a struct variable declared with dynamic allocation. How is this possible?

Comment: c does not have references, `new` or `delete`.

Comment: Do not return dynamically allocated objects by reference if it's the caller's responsibility to `delete` it. Just return by value and use `std::unique_ptr` if you *need* to return a pointer to a dynamically allocated object.

Comment: Why do you use C syntax with question tag of C++? It is not the same thing... ```typedef struct``` = C, ```struct Name {};``` = C++... ```class```, ```std::vector```, ```using namespace``` etc.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @KorelK Sorry. 
I have been studying c ++ since I have just studied a book related to c language.

Comment: @박서형 Take a recommendation from me- start with pure C, and after you got this whole language, start with learning about OOP (Object Oriented Programming). Then begin with C++. The differece between them is critical in their idea, and can be very confusing without the understanding of the difference between OOP and Procedural Programming.

Answer (score 0):

Note: do not use `typedef struct` in C++, it is C idiom and does nothing but harm in C++. Just define it and probably add some ctors:

```
struct Point
{
    int xpos = 0;
    int ypos = 0;

    Point() = default;
    Point( int x, int y ) : xpos( x ), ypos( y ) {}
};
```

> First of all, I have a question about how to declare a variable to return a local variable as a reference type.

You cannot return reference to local variable, as it would lead to dangling reference. Though it is possible to make this "work" using static variable it is not a good solution, you better change this function to return by value.

> Inside the definition of a function, however, it returns a struct variable declared with dynamic allocation. How is this possible?

You return reference to dynamically allocated object by dereferencing it, which finally leads to ugly hack of deleting address of a reference. You should never do that. If a function suppose to return dynamically allocated object - use a smart pointer to clearly show your intention. In this case it is not necessary, you should just return object by value:

```
Point PA(const Point &p1, const Point &p2)
{
    Point p;
    p.xpos = p1.xpos + p2.xpos;
    p.ypos = p1.ypos + p2.ypos;
    return p;
}
```

or if you added ctors as mentioned above it is as short as:

```
Point PA(const Point &p1, const Point &p2)
{
    return Point( p1.xpos + p2.xpos, p1.ypos + p2.ypos );
}
```

and main becomes much shorter as well:

```
int main()
{
    Point p1( 3, 20 );
    Point p2( 70, 7 );
    Point r = PA(p1, p2);
    std::cout << r.posx << "," << r.posy << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your function `PA()` returns no object, but a reference to an object (a `Point`) initialized to refer to the object at address `pptr`.

References are like pointers, but can be used as if they are the real thing (=object). Unlike pointers, references cannot be assigned (in order to refer to another object), but bind to the same object (assigning to a reference means assigning to the referred object) during their whole life time. This implies that references must be initialized, but also that references may be dangling (for example in your code `ref` is dangling after `delete &ref;`).